# Node.js - Really large streams are blocking and CPU intensive

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming

We've got a few database calls that easily stream 100K records. The issue we're having is that whenever we use one of these streams, it pegs the CPU and seems to block all other processes.

I've tried a few different hacks to mitigate this, but am a bit stuck now. Here's my most recent attempt at piping the stream to a Transform where it uses `process.nextTick`.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util   = require('util');

function StreamThrottler() {
  stream.Transform.call(this, { objectMode: true });
}

util.inherits(StreamThrottler, stream.Transform);

StreamThrottler.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {

  process.nextTick(function() {
      console.log('chunk');
      // note: I'm intentionally not pushing the chunk 
      // onto the stream for testing
      cb();
  });
};

StreamThrottler.prototype._flush = function(cb) {
  cb();
};

var streamThrottler = new StreamThrottler();

// now the db call
this.largeDatabaseResultStream().pipe(streamThrottler);
```

I noticed [this](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/issues/47) Node.js issue that may or may not be related.

Does anyone have any other thoughts on how to address this?

Comment: It might help to include the name of the database module you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/pekim/tedious

Answer (score 0):

When you use `objectMode: true` the native stream implementation may have to buffer and serialize the data.

So the idea of using a throttler stream is a good one, so maybe this stream would use `objectMode: false` and down stream, you could use the convenient `objectMode: true`.

Note that mixing streams of different kind may give you some errors.
`{objectMode: false} ==> {objectMode: true}` is ok (buffer is just another kind of object)
`{objectMode: true} ==> {objectMode: false}` is not ok (unless the data is a buffer itself)

Comment: take a look at promises and generator's `next` method. They might come handy.